# Issue with Removing Members from Pool and Adding Them Back to Respective Families in React using state

Tags: reactjs, react-state

code link : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/friendly-rain-d3w9w2

Families are initially loaded from the familysData array.

Each family is rendered as a card, and the members of each family are displayed in a list.

You have an "Add to Pool" button for each family member. When clicked, the member should be removed from the family's list and added to the swimming pool.

The swimming pool is divided into small and large pools, depending on the age of the members. Members under 18 go to the small pool, while those 18 and older go to the large pool.

The swimming pool component should display the members currently in the pool, and there should be a "Remove from Pool" button for each member. Clicking this button should remove the member from the pool and add them back to their respective family.

Shows error on clicking "Remove from Pool" button :Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.